# How do I "unset" a layout in a window in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a window which has a layout.

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

coolLayout1 = QGridlayout()
coolLayout2 = QGridLayout()

"""
[a bunch of widgets here]
"""

window.setLayout(coolLayout1) #will set the window's layout to this QGridLayout
window.setLayout(coolLayout2) #won't set the layout because it already has one
```

How do I "unset" the first layout so that the second one can be set instead?

Comment: It's rarely required to change a layout: for grid layouts, you can just add the widgets again, while for boxed layouts you can re-add widgets in the new order. Are you trying to show another "page" in the current widget with different child widgets, switching to a new "view" (and eventually switch it back if needed)?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty muich exactly what I'm going for.

Comment: Then use [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

Comment: QStackedWidget is a great choice, but you can also check out the other container widgets like [QTabWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html) and [QToolBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbox.html). You might even want a [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html)

Comment: To elaborate, as I'm still having issues, @musicamante.
I have 2 QGridLayouts that have different widgets.
One of them is loaded at the start and contains a "Play" button. I want it to switch to the second layout upon clicking "Play". 
I also don't write using "self.<whatever>" or "\_\_init__", I write it with regular variables as I find it way more readable.

Comment: Then you need to connect that button to a function that switches to the desired page. Note that while you can do this with simple labdas, in the long run it won't be effective and will create more issues than benefit. By what you're describing, it seems that you don't use subclassing, but in python and Qt world that is almost inevitable. If you find it less readable it's probably a matter of habit, as being able to tell apart local variables and instance members is actually extremely important (and rather easy with the usage of `self`).